# Rake: How to accept command-line arguments which include a hypen? (when using the key=value syntax)

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a Rake task which accepts multiple command-line arguments. I prefer to support the key=value syntax for passing parameters to the task, such as:

```
rake deploy verbose=true environment=production dry-run=true
```

The problem I have is that "dry-run" argument. After running that Rake task, I get the message:

> Don't know how to build task 'dry-run=true'

It doesn't matter if "dry-run" is the first, middle or last argument on the command-line. I could accept the arguments using the "array" style:

```
rake deploy[true,production,true]
```

But I don't like that, and I could remove the hypen:

```
rake deploy verbose=true environment=production dryrun=true
```

But I was hoping there was some way of allowing a hyphen in the argument name but I haven't been able to find anything, anywhere that discusses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables are managed by your shell. When `rake` does `ENV['verbose']` he's just asking the shell, "hey, do you have any value called 'verbose'? If yes, give it to me".

Shells are generally not able to handle hypens in their variable names; like in most programming languages, the hypen is reserved for the substraction operation.

The simplest fix would be replacing the hyphen by an underscore:

```
rake deploy verbose=true environment=production dry_run=true
```

EDIT:

Another option would be using something more suited for command line management. [thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor) should allow you to define a command like so:

```
deploy --verbose --environment=production --dry-run
```

EDIT2:

It turns out that the values are passed verbatim to rake, not handled by the shell as I thought - see first comment on this answer for details. The solutions proposed on this answer work nevertheless.

Comment: This isn’t quite right. Key value pairs specified _before_ the command name are handled by the shell, but those added _after_ are just passed as command line args to the process. [Rake checks its args for any matching a `key=value` pattern, and adds any it finds to the environment](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/v0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb#L543-553). The pattern doesn’t allow `-`, so `dry-run=true` doesn’t match and is added as a task. The effect is basically the same (I suspect Rake deliberately mirrored the shell behaviour), but the explanation is a bit more involved.

Comment: @matt thanks for the clarification, I've chosen to go with dry_run for now.